# Getting message DSolve::conarg:

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a simple linear PDE about $p_0$ which is a function of ξ, ζ and τ. However, the boundary condition is defined at `ζ = h`, which is a function of ξ and τ. The other quantities are all constant. In fact, this PDE can be solved by hand. I want to find p0 as a function of `h` and ζ. I just want to verify it, then I will try another more complex one.

[image]

The solution I want is as follows which is obtained by hand.

[image]

I tried the following code, but it does not work.

```
DSolve[
 {D[Subscript[p, 0][
     h[ξ, τ], ζ], ζ] == (R/
       Pr)*(1 - ζ*(h[ξ, τ] + k)^-1) - G, (2/3)*
    Subscript[p, 0][h[ξ, τ], h[ξ, τ]] == 
   e^2* d^(-1)*((h[ξ, τ] + k)^-1)^2 - 
    2*s*D[h[ξ, τ], {ξ, 2}]
  },
 Subscript[p, 0][
  h[ξ, τ], ζ], {h[ξ, τ], ζ}
 ]
```

I get the message

> DSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently. >>

Comment: The `DSolve` command you give does not evaluate in Mathematica. If you fix that it's more likely you'll receive an answer.

Answer (score 3):

No one seems to want to explain to you why or how this answer doesn't compute, only that it doesn't compute. It's a very quick-fix.

The syntax of `DSolve` works like this:

```
DSolve[{eqn1,eqn2,...},function[var],var]
```

But here, `var` indicates only the independent variable you are looking for and not the other variables with respect to which you are not solving the ODE. If you change `{h[ξ, τ], ζ}` to just `ζ` your code should work.

```
DSolve[
 {D[Subscript[p, 0][
     h[ξ, τ], ζ], ζ] == (R/
       Pr)*(1 - ζ*(h[ξ, τ] + k)^-1) - G, (2/3)*
    Subscript[p, 0][h[ξ, τ], h[ξ, τ]] == 
   e^2* d^(-1)*((h[ξ, τ] + k)^-1)^2 - 
    2*s*D[h[ξ, τ], {ξ, 2}]
  },
 Subscript[p, 0][
  h[ξ, τ], ζ], ζ
 ]
```

This may spit out a mess, but you can check:

```
%[[1, 1, 2]] == (3/2) e^2 d^(-1) (k + h[ξ, τ])^(-2) - 
 3 s D[h[ξ, τ], {ξ, 2}] +
 (G - R/Pr) (h[ξ, τ] - ζ) +
 (R (h[ξ, τ]^2 - ζ^2)/(2 Pr (k + h[ξ, τ])))//FullSimplify
```

Comment: You say you've got it, but just in case, the output of any solve type command is a list of rules. This takes the first rule from the first solution and takes whatever the assignment actually is. In other words, it takes `{{var->foo}}` and instead gives you `foo`.